# multi level ssh to pull and push git repo

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I recently setup gitosis . Here is the scenario. I setup gitosis on Server S1 and multiple users have logins and all their id_rsa.pub have been setup so that their commits as a user get commited to the shared repos S1 w/o password and configured for various projects.

Is it a possibility that one/any user can user user1 their own host H1 to fetch/clone code from gitosis@S1 as user1 from the server S1 to H1 . There are ssh keys configured to access for user user1@ from user1@H1 to user1@S1 and user1@S1 to gitosis@S1 .

Pulls data :

> **user1@S1: $** git clone gitosis@S1.com:proj1 proj1

Does not pull data because of credentials

> **user1@H1: $** git clone gitosis@S1.com:proj1 proj1

Cloning the data from H1 to S1 for user1 would not allow commits because of bare vs nonbare repo

> **user1@H1: $** git clone user1@S1.com:path/proj1 proj1

Is there a way to give a recursive command so that it pulls the data from gitosis@S1.com to user1@H1 in order to allow mask the end user the problem of having new public keys added to the gitosis config whenever some user wants to do his work from a different host.

I am not sure which forum this question would fall into , since this involves ssh keys , git, configuration, behavior.

**Note** : I would not prefer to use ssh-fs or any other mounting techniques to use the files from S1 to H1.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add their public keys to the gitosis server?  Or have them use dedicated keys for gitosis that they have installed on both S1 and H1?  Then there's nothing more to install.

Comment: H1 is subject to change and setting up the H1 key is a little bit of manual process ( editing of the config file) to include the new user . Although this can be scripted to some extent.